# Pass and then parse code samples from JSON in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

So... Hey everyone, v'got another question... Currently I am building own website-blog (from scratch for the purpose of self-education) that will contain some funny staff and some smart stuff (like articles with my code), *now* it's just a *static* site that works due to Angular.js. One day it will be dynamic with RoR at backend, but, never mind, now about *issue* that I have faced yesterday. For example: I've got route for all 'smart' posts looks like:

```
.state('smartStuff', {
  url: '/smartStuff',
  views: {
    'content': {
      templateUrl: 'html/smartStuff.html',
      controller: 'SmartStuffController'
    }
  }
})
```

Then, single post's page create dynamically:

```
.state('postsAboutSmartStuff', {
  url: '/smartStuff/{smartStuffPostId}',
  views: {
    'content': {
      templateUrl: 'html/post.html',
      controller: 'SmartStuffController'
    }
  }
})
```

Content that I represent in each post I get from JSON via service...

```
angular.module('postsServices', [])
.factory('postsFactory', function($http) {
    var promise;
    return {
        all: function() {
            if(!promise) {
                promise = $http.get('postsSmartStuff.json')
                    .then(function(response) {
                        return response.data;
                    })
            }
            return promise;
        }
    }
});
```

and then controller... like:

```
var postsControllers = angular.module('postsControllers', []);
postsControllers.controller('SmartStuffController', function($scope, postsFactory, $stateParams) {
  postsFactory.all()
      .then(function(posts) {
          $scope.posts = posts;
          $scope.smartStuffPostId = $stateParams.smartStuffPostId;

          function getById(arr, id) {
             for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                  if (arr[i].id == id) {
                      return arr[i];
                  }
             }
          }
          $scope.singlePost = getById($scope.posts, $stateParams.smartStuffPostId);

      });
});
```

ALL WORKS FINE! When my JSON looks like:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "theme": "vanilla javascript",
    "title": "Post 2",
    "description": "Description two"
 },
 {...}, 
]
```

I mean when I 'give' my JSON just TEXT. **But** as I have already mentioned - I *want and will* write some actual code in my articles... So, at last, my question - **How** can I pass any real code and then correctly parse in Angular's controller? I *feel* that it's very bad practice to pass code(functions, wateva) like this, but now I do not see other solutions. I'm just learning so *sorry anyway* and any decent help will be greatly appreciated. *Hope* I make myself absolutely clear :)

Comment: When you say "pass and parse", do you mean you want to actually have the browser execute the code in your article?  That's just a really bad idea.  If you mean you want to display them as code samples, then we can help with that.

Comment: @Paul you are right, I mean represent code samples, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to actually store your text as Markdown, and then use a markdown directive such as this one: https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive to display all your text.

/* UPDATE */
To be clear, what I meant was that your *content* should be in Markdown.  So each post would still be some kind of JSON object, but whatever data element you're using to represent the body of your post (not clear from above) or any other part of the post that should have formatted content should be in Markdown, and then passed to an Angular directive that can transform that Markdown into HTML.

So for example, you might have a JSON object like:

````
{
    "id": 1,
    "theme": "vanilla javascript",
    "title": "Post 2",
    "description": "Description two",
    "content" : "Hey, I have some awesome content here: ```var t = 'awesome'; alert(t); ```"
 }
````

Then you fetch it like you already do, but when you instantiate the `angular-markdown-directive`, you'd bind that directive to your content:

```
<!-- Assuming 'content' is in the current scope; might have to be singlePost.content or something else --> 
<div btf-markdown="content">
</div>
```

or possibly:

```
<btf-markdown>{{singlePost.content}}</btf-markdown>
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul, I'll try. Don't you have any real examples that use this?

Comment: ? The github link should show you how to do it.  Markdown for code samples is demonstrated on the cheatsheet: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code .  What else do you need?

Comment: All right, I'll figure this out. Thank you once more.

Comment: man, I've tried, if I got you right you suggested to store data as Markdown INSTEAD of JSON? If yes - then I dunno how to get now that data via service... It has to be key -> value... But maybe you meant write data in Markdown and then transform it into JSON... again I'm stucked :) too low experience (;

Comment: I've got only one post.html but it has contain different content dependin on post.id... that's why I use JSON... how to achieve this using Markdown I don't understand at this very moment

Comment: yeah, got u, but there's still an issue - in that Markdown thing whitespaces in codeblocks means new line, but JSON do not understand whitespaces...

Comment: JSON doesn't define any limitations on whitespace inside the string literals.  It ignores, etc, whitespace outside the string literals.  JSON doesn't have to "understand" anything inside your quotes. http://www.json.org/

Comment: man you do not understand me - I mean I need to show each code sample correctly - in few lines, not in one line. In that Markdown you just write code in few lines - one under another. _BUT_ in JSON I can't perform that!!! It can be done like: one line <br> second line ... but obviously it's ugly way... anyway I will solve that :) interesting stuff.